# Uninstall XAMPP on mac

Tags: xampp, root

Not long ago, I installed XAMPP, and I wanted to change the root password. But i did bad commands in the wampp's terminal and I couldn't access to phpmyadmin. So i did "sudo rm -r /opt/lampp" but it only deleted the configs files. And now I'm stuck because I can't access to anythings and I don't even have the permissions to lauch the "uninstall" file into /opt/lampp, so I can't delete /opt/lampp to reset XAMPP. I really need help ! Thanks.

Comment: This is an English language site. Please ask in English rather than French. Thanks.

Comment: Having same problem any solution found yet?